# React Native sticky footer with TextInput

Tags: ios, react-native

The problems statement is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692880/uiscrollview-with-sticky-footer-uiview-and-dynamic-height-content/21770179#21770179)

But I am looking for some pointers to implement the same with react-native.

I am building a chat window (like iMessage, whatsapp) where messages(ListView) come on top with a sticky footer containing a TextInput.

I am able to get a sticky footer, but when someone tries to enter text with TextInput in footer, the keyboard hides the TextInput. I tried approaches mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313244/how-to-auto-slide-the-window-out-from-behind-keyboard-when-textinput-has-focus), but none seem to work because of presence of ListView above.

Here is what my current layout code looks like:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
          <ListView
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
            keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          />
          <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                 <TextInput/>
          </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: have another view below the view with the text input. on focus on text input, increase the height of the the bottom view equal to the height of the keyboard.

Comment: Will absolute positioning work or would the ListView have to move up as well?

Comment: I would like to see if there's any best practice on doing this which cover both IOS and Android platform too!

Comment: Maybe will be helpful after you read this https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/master/src/InputToolbar.js#L25

You can see the input component is not always position absolute. And this library works perfectly in iOS and Android.

Comment: Have you considered using the KeyboardAvoidingView? https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview